# Geolocation not working with Phonegap Build after adding config.xml

Tags: android, cordova, geolocation

I have coded a small geolocation application using HTML and Javascript. I am using Phonegap to build it.

Geolocation worked fine until adding the config.xml file. I have added all the correct permissions for Phonegap (3.1.0).

Here's the relevant bits of code:

```
<!--
Enable individual API permissions here.
The "device" permission is required for the 'deviceready' event.
-->
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/device" />
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>

<preference name="permissions" value="INTERNET" />
```

Here's the full code, if interested: https://github.com/wolffe/LifeMap, and here's the app: https://build.phonegap.com/apps/725755/builds

**EDIT #1:** It works in browser.

**EDIT #2:** I have removed the Cordova plugin permission.

**EDIT #3:** I have removed the config.xml file and it now works again. Using Phonegap Build 3.1.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that the Cordova geolocation plugin works very well - the developers agreed to deprecate the geolocation plugin [pretty recently](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/cordova-dev/201401.mbox/%3CCAOBL_k4A6+0i_sHD+qpY7PXbEMATe+onR6EyhBT0G-w_N812rw@mail.gmail.com%3E) because the Web Geolocation provided by the browser works as well or better in some cases.

I think you should remove the geolocation plugin from your project. You should be able to keep all of your JavaScript the same since I'm pretty sure it's the same API. I'm not sure about the permissions or not, but since it's Web GPS I'd think you don't have to include special permissions.

Comment: It still doesn't work (with no special permissions). The idea is that it worked before adding the config.xml file, using the HTML5/Javascript Geolocation API.

Comment: Right. In the config.xml you now have the 'geolocation' feature added, which I assume will add the geolocation plugin into the project. Can you remove that feature line and see if it works? I'd expect it to revert back to Web GPS.

Comment: Yes, I have also updated my original question. There is no special permission now in config.xml.

Comment: Try removing `<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>` from config.xml and see if that works.

Comment: Still not working. I'm trying to build it for older versions, such as 2.9.0.